# Why do I get a 401 unauthorized error when logging in?

Tags: next.js, formik, http-status-code-401, next-auth, credential-providers

I am using the NextAuth.js credentials provider for the log in procedure.
When logging in I am catching the errors in a try-catch block and set the error state accordingly, but I do not display the error state anywhere yet. Even though I am catching the errors, a 401 unauthorized gets thrown when trying to log in. I am using wrong credentials, thus expecting an error called CredentialsSignin which I am getting, but additionally I am getting the 401 every time. The problem is that I am not able to detect where it is thrown, that might be the reason I am not able to handle it.

[image: 401 thrown in console]

Here the code of my custom log in page:

```
import { InferGetServerSidePropsType } from "next"
import { CtxOrReq } from "next-auth/client/_utils";
import { getCsrfToken, getSession, signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik"
import * as Yup from "yup"

export default function Login({ csrfToken }: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const router = useRouter()

    type Credentials = {
        email: string
        password: string
    }

    let credentials: Credentials;

    const handleLogin = useCallback(async (credentials) => {
        if (!credentials.email) {
            return setError('email is missing')
        }
        if (!credentials.password) {
            return setError('password is missing')
        }
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            const response: any = await signIn('credentials', { ...credentials, redirect: false }) // find right type
            if (response.error && response.error === 'CredentialsSignin') {
                setError('email or password are wrong')
            } else {
                setError('')
                router.push('/')
            }
        } catch {
            setError('login failed')
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }, [router])

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            email: Yup.string()
                .required("email address is required"),
            password: Yup.string()
                .required("password is required")
        }),
        onSubmit: values => {
            credentials = {
                email: values.email,
                password: values.password
            }
            handleLogin(credentials)
        }
    })

    return (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
            <label>
                Email
                <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    value={formik.values.email}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur} />
            </label>
            {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email && <p>{formik.errors.email}</p>}
            <label>
                Password
                <input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    value={formik.values.password}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur} />
            </label>
            {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password && <p>{formik.errors.password}</p>}
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context: CtxOrReq | undefined) {

    const session = await getSession(context)

    if (session) {
        return {
            redirect: { destination: '/' }
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            csrfToken: await getCsrfToken(context)
        },
    }
}
```

Here the code of my [...nextauth].ts API page:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import { prisma } from '../../../prisma/prisma_client'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs'

export default NextAuth({

  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {}
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials) {
          return null
        }

        const { email } = credentials
        const { password } = credentials

        const storedUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email
          }, select: {
            id: true,
            email: true,
            hashedPassword: true,
            company: {
              select: {
                id: true,
                name: true
              }
            }
          }
        })

        if (!storedUser) {
          return null
        }

        const user = {
          id: storedUser?.id,
          email,
          comanyId: storedUser?.company?.id,
          companyName: storedUser?.company?.name,
        }

        const validatePassword = await compare(password, storedUser.hashedPassword)
        return validatePassword ? user : null
      }
    })
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      user && (token.user = user)
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user
      return session
    }
  },

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
  }
})
```

Comment: Isn't the 401 error the response you get from the API that then triggers the `CredentialsSignin` error on the client code? That would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: This is what I thought too, but why am I not able to catch it then? and why is it not mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: The error isn't thrown, you know it errored by checking the `response.error` field. See https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option.

Comment: @juliomalves I added a picture to my question that shows the thrown error in the console and I am clearly not logging it.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No and this really makes me sad. I really looked up the whole internet to find a solution or explanation to this. I would highly appreciate any help or suggestions. I still don't know if the 401 is the standard answer to a failed login from the signin-function and even if it is, why I am unable to catch it.

Comment: Same here, some API routes in NextJS just randomly give 401, even on a GET that I browse or redirect to within the browser…

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure, that you set 'withCredentials' to 'true' for your API object

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and manage to resolve it. The first block of code below is the buggy version and the second block is the working version.

So, there's a few things to note:

- I returned the same data for `catch` and `response` because I wanted to determine if the issue was cause by the data which was returned. But it wasn't the case, so this was reverted in the working version.
- In the working version, there's `return` for the promise and a `return` within the promise. My understanding is that the `response` and `catch` blocks are functions by itself, and returning within the inner block will not propagate the value such that it is returned by the `authorize` function. In other words, I'm returning nothing - resulting in `401`.
- With the same understanding, the issue with OP's code is it is always failing to return a user object. Without running the code, I can't pinpoint it for sure but there are a few possible paths which leads to so.

```js
authorize: async (credentials) => {
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/signin/', {
    email: credentials.email,
    id: credentials.id
}).then((response) => {
    const user = { id: 1, token: "1234", name: 'John', email: 'john@abc.com' }
    return user
}).catch((e) => {
    const user = { id: 1, token: "1234", name: 'John', email: 'john@abc.com' }
    return user
});
};
```

```js
authorize: async (credentials) => {
const request = axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/signin/', {
    email: credentials.email,
    id: credentials.id
})

return await request.then((response) => {
    const user = { id: 1, token: "1234", name: 'John', email: 'john@abc.com' }
    return user
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
});
};
```